# Separating data from an associative array index wise in php

Tags: php, associative-array, array-map

I know that i will be using array_map for this but the issue it keeps saying

> notice Undefined index: DeviceID.....

I am trying to Separate `DeviceID` as `$key` and all its values as `$value`

```
//Code
$output = array_map(null,$getTheHistoricData['DeviceID']);

//Array
array (size=4112)
0 => 
array (size=5)
  'DeviceID' => string '1' (length=1)
  'DeviceTimestamp' => string '2018-09-22 00:00:11' (length=19)
  'LineTemp' => string '22.2148' (length=7)
  'LineCurrent' => string '232.562' (length=7)
  'RxRSSI' => string '0' (length=1)
1 => 
array (size=5)
  'DeviceID' => string '1' (length=1)
  'DeviceTimestamp' => string '2018-09-22 00:00:33' (length=19)
  'LineTemp' => string '22.2154' (length=7)
  'LineCurrent' => string '234.672' (length=7)
  'RxRSSI' => string '0' (length=1)
2 => 
array (size=5)
  'DeviceID' => string '1' (length=1)
  'DeviceTimestamp' => string '2018-09-22 00:00:55' (length=19)
  'LineTemp' => string '22.2094' (length=7)
  'LineCurrent' => string '233.954' (length=7)
  'RxRSSI' => string '0' (length=1)
and so on
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) as shown in bottom to do this work.

```
$output = array_map(function($val){
    return $val['DeviceID'];
}, $getTheHistoricData);
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/GEjki)

Also you can use [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) instead

```
$output = array_column($getTheHistoricData, 'DeviceID');
```